# isomorphism and restriction/corestriction

Tags: abstract-algebra

Assume we have an isomorphism of abelian groups $A \to B$ and restriction maps $A' \to A$ and $B' \to B$ and corestriction maps $A \to A'$ and $B \to B'$ such that $cores \circ res$ is an isomorphism on $A'$ and $B'$.  So $res$ is injective and $cores$ is surjective. Does it follow that $A' \to B'$ is an isomorphism as well?

Edit: Assume that the $res$ and $cores$ maps are compatible with $A \to B$ and $A' \to B'$ and we are given a $A' \to B'$

I think I can prove that $A' \to B'$ is injective.

Comment: What do you mean by "compatible"? Is it $res \circ g = f \circ res$ and $g \circ cores = cores \circ f$?

Comment: (where $f: A \rightarrow B$ and $g: A' \rightarrow B'$)

Comment: Yes, this is what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the functions $f: A \rightarrow B$ and $g: A' \rightarrow B'$. Then "compatible" means that $res \circ g = f \circ res$ and $g \circ cores = cores \circ f$.

We claim that $g^{-1} = cores \circ f^{-1} \circ res$. Proof:

$cores \circ f^{-1} \circ res \circ g = cores \circ res = id_{A'}$

$g \circ cores \circ f^{-1} \circ res = cores \circ res = id_{B'}$

Comment: So it is true. Thank you!